# Как вывести список всех файлов находящихся в папках и под папках php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести список всех файлов находящихся в папках и под папках php.

Answer (score 1):

Поработаю гуглом:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;

    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        echo '<li>'.$ff;
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('Main Dir');
```

Взял [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121479/listing-all-the-folders-subfolders-and-files-in-a-directory-using-php), автор [Shef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645186/shef).

Еще способ:

```
<?php
$dir   = '/path/to/directory';
$files = scandir($dir);

print_r($files);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием объекта-итератора *DirectoryIterator*:

```
<?php
function files($folder)
{
    $res = [];
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($folder);
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDot()) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
            $res = array_merge($res, files($fileinfo->getPathname()));
            continue;
        }
        $res[] = $fileinfo->getPathname();
    }
    return $res;
}

var_dump(files("/path/to/folder"));
```